# Количество вхождений паттерна в строке C++

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Привет всем! Как посчитать количество вхождений паттерна regex в сроке? Язык С++

```
    std::string subject("This is a test test");
    try {
        std::regex re("\\w+");
        std::sregex_iterator next(subject.begin(), subject.end(), re);
        std::sregex_iterator end;
        while (next != end) {
            std::smatch match = *next;
            std::cout << match.str() << "\n";
            std::cout << match.size() << " count" << std::endl;
            next++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Покажите пример, или укажите библиотеку через которую у вас реализован regex.

Comment: #include <regex> извините, не могу вставить код. Подключить подсветку

Comment: проблема выше, в названии темы

Comment: нужна функция, вроде getline, чтобы читать уже готовую строку. Потом, с помощью count вытянуть количество одинаковых слов. К сожалению получаю только общее количество слов в string

Comment: Напишите, что именно нужно. Пока что неясно, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: Виктор, спасибо. Я пока разбираюсь, поэтому молчу. Вы все верно написали. Но зачем то стёрли)

Comment: А что было правильно? Какой должен быть результат? `1`? Тогда мой ответ неправильный.

Comment: 5 - на заданный вопрос ответ верный. 1 - неверно, согласен.

Comment: Вернул на прежнее место.

Comment: std::smatch::size ?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [`std::distance`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

> Возвращает количество элементов между `first` и `last`.

Вот пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex  re("\\w+");
    std::string subject("This is a test test");

    std::ptrdiff_t match_count(std::distance(
        std::sregex_iterator(subject.begin(), subject.end(), re),
        std::sregex_iterator()));

    std::cout << match_count << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Демо на IDEONE.com](http://ideone.com/yHpnWx)

Всего 5 вхождений искомого шаблона.

Comment: Спасибо. Это я и получаю. Вопрос задал неверно, получить количество одинаковых вхождений слов в результате работы паттерна.