# Вывести количество совпадений в регулярном выражении C++

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте. Вот пример текстового файла

```
FIO: Mitkevich Vladislav Ivanocich
Eployee id: 20
Experience (in hours): 178
Salary per hour: 15
Resulting salary: 2670
Bonus: 5019.6


FIO: Sidorov Ivan Andreevich

Eployee id: 29
Experience (in hours): 84
Salary per hour: 12
Resulting salary: 1008
Bonus: 887.04
```

Мне нужно узнать какое кол-во ID у меня присутствует в документе
Вот мой код по поиску ID:

```
int lineno = 0;
for (string line;  getline(fin,line); )
{
    ++lineno;
    smatch matches;
    if (regex_search(line, matches, RegEx))
        employeid = //Вот тут я не знаю что писать
}
```

где RegEx - это запрос, а fin - это сам файл

```
regex RegEx{ "(id)" }; //Шаблон
ifstream fin("db_employee.txt");
```

employeid - это естественно сам ID.
За ранее спасибо!

Comment: `matches[0]` будет соответствовать `std::string` пойманного паттерна. Переведите в число, и всё. Можно `matches.str(0)` использовать. В результате: `employeid = std::stoi(matches.str(0));`

Comment: employeid = matches.str(0) + 1; Выдаёт ошибку, employeid у меня типа float, но влиять это не должно, как по мне

Comment: float?! Он же целочисленный. Да и почитайте ещё раз комментарий.

Comment: Посмотрите [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/646379/182013).

Comment: А у вас ID могут что ли повторятся ? Если нет - то вам не надо ничего анализировать, раз match, значит count++. Хотя паттерн стоило бы сделать более точным `Eployee id:` а то он у вас всяких `id` в фамилиях наловит